# Absolute Galois group of Q and stratification of moduli space of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces, absolute-galois-group

This is slightly related, but distinct from, a question I asked earlier.

The moduli space of ribbon graphs with metric (with all vertices having degree at least 3) is isomorphic to the moduli space of (decorated) smooth complex curves of genus g with n marked points. (cf. Kontsevich's "Feynman diagrams and low-dimensional topology).

But this moduli space of ribbon graphs with metric is naturally stratified by the underlying combinatorial type of ribbon graph (i.e "it breaks up into pieces" where each piece corresponds to exactly one underlying ribbon graph). By Grothendieck's dessin correspondence (and extensions thereof), isomorphism classes of ribbon graphs are in one-to-one correspondence with isomorphism classes of algebraic curves defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ (cf. https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/9811024).
This means that the moduli space of curves can be partitioned into pieces where each piece corresponds to a unique $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ curve.

1. How well-studied is this?
2. Given a $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ curve, can we explicitly say which other complex curves correspond to the same piece of the partition?
3. Can this partition be given a group/ring/etc structure? Does the obvious $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ action (by acting on the coefficients defining the curve) on the entire partition have any interesting features?
4. Does the isomorphism of moduli spaces preserve strata? (Kontsevich says that the moduli of curves is stratified by "euclidean spaces of some dimension modulo some finite groups" - I don't know what he means precisely, but can the $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ stratification correspond to another nice stratification on the moduli of curves)?

Comment: There's no 1-to-1 correspondence. Different ribbon graphs can give you the same curve.

Comment: Really? In particular, the paper linked above says that there is a bijection on the (first sentence) of the second page. This is repeated in the review of this paper on Mathscinet as well. ... (Perhaps I should have said "connected" ribbon graphs instead.)

Comment: "Grothendieck discovered that there is a natural bijection between the set of
isomorphism classes of connected ribbon graphs and the set of isomorphism classes of of Belyi maps." Belyi maps are not algebraic curves defined over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$. They are algebraic curves defined over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$, plus extra data.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Is "algebraic curves defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ are in bijection with Riemann surfaces admitting a Belyi map, but such Riemann surfaces may admit more than one Belyi map, so picking the Belyi map is picking extra data" what is happening here?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: One point that still confuses me - a point in the moduli space of metric ribbon graphs corresponds uniquely to a point in the above moduli space of curves, but if two distinct ribbon graphs give the same curve over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, equipping all edges of both with length 1, they would correspond to the same point in the moduli space of curves. What am I missing? (Is the decoration on the moduli space of curves what is making the difference?)

Comment: Yes, the decoration is quite significant here.